# How do I stop the docker service from always using all of its allocated ram on my host?

Tags: windows-10, memory, docker, docker-for-windows

The docker service on Windows 10 seems to always use the maximum amount of memory it is permitted to allocate. For example, when I increased the memory in the Resources -> Advanced section from 2GB to 8GB and clicked on "Apply & Restart", this happened in task manager:

[image]

How can I get docker to only use memory when/if needed by any running containers, as opposed to just chewing it all up?

No containers are currently running, just the service.

Comment: Perhaps you don't understand how and why Docker requires and reserves memory? For virtualization systems, reserved memory remains allocated to the service so that it can be assigned quickly and won't have to wait for the host OS to free it up before it can be used. So, instead of asking how to get Docker not to use all the memory that it has been assigned, perhaps you need to rethink your configuration and perhaps install more memory in your computer.

Comment: @music2myear Is there any way to make it behave differently, so it doesn't use up all of the memory?

Comment: @quant - No; What you want isn’t possible

Comment: Why the down vote? That first comment seems like a good answer once you remove the sass, but it's not a bad question is it?

Comment: Also, if it really is the case that this can't be changed, it seems like a pretty bad limitation of docker. Is this something that's going to get fixed?

Comment: Like I said in the first comment, this question is based on a misunderstanding of what Docker is, what this setting does, and why Hypervisors function this way. To "change" this would require rewriting Docker, and it's not a bug.

Comment: It looks like this feature was already requested here: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/521

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Running the newer versions of docker desktop with the WSL2 backend resolves this problem. I can't give much more details than this as I don't understand it too well myself, but I've installed WSL2 and noticed that docker now allocates memory dynamically.

> Docker Desktop uses the dynamic memory allocation feature in WSL 2 to
> greatly improve the resource consumption. This means, Docker Desktop
> only uses the required amount of CPU and memory resources it needs,
> while enabling CPU and memory-intensive tasks such as building a
> container to run much faster.

Source: [Docker Desktop WSL 2 backend](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/)

Comment: Glad you solved this, but there was no mention of WSL in your question. Presenting complete questions is a significant part of getting good answers.

Answer (score -1):

While Docker differs from full hardware virtualization, it still functions in many of the same ways, and for the same reasons.

Hypervisors reserve the given amount of memory in order that this memory will be available to them and the containers (or virtual machines) when they require it without having to petition the OS for this memory.

The setting you set is specifically for this purpose and behaves in precisely the way you have observed for precisely this reason. It is not a bug, and to change how it behaves is to rewrite the basic behavior of Docker.

So, nothing is broken and things are behaving as they should.

I strongly suggest you read up on memory reservations in Docker to better understand how and why. Docker is a mature product and is, I assume, well documented.

To "solve" the issue you have come up against, install more memory or more carefully plan your Docker memory needs and use this setting as it was designed, not just on a whim as you are doing now.

Comment: I think this isn't a bad answer in its content but the tone seems overly defensive. It makes me wonder whether you've really investigated a solution. I'm also skeptical of thinly veiled "you should read up on X" style comments. I'm going to leave this question open for a bit longer in case a better response comes along, otherwise I'll mark this as the answer later.

Comment: "Thinly veiled..."? OK. You asked "How do I stop Docker...". The answer to that is that you cannot. Why it does not is secondary and so I spent a brief bit explaining the basics, and after hopefully giving you enough information to recognize that your question is based on wrong assumptions and incorrect ideas, I directed you to fix that problem by reading up and gave you specific topics to do this research and reading on. But, ok. You're entitled to your opinion.

Comment: Eventually I found a solution to this myself, which I've posted it as a [separate answer](https://superuser.com/a/1586839/270774).